# Unicode locale error while running lollypop music player

Tags: music

When I try to run the lollypop music player, I get the following error "Lollypop isn't designed to work without an unicode locale. Please fix your system". How to solve this?[image]

Edit: My etc/default/locale file:

```
  `LANG="en_IN"
   LANGUAGE="en_IN:en"`
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste or pastebin your etc/default /locale file?

Comment: @bitseater Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in terminal :

```
localectl set-locale "LANG=en_IN.utf8"

localectl set-locale "LANGUAGE=en_IN.utf8"
```

Check again your /etc/default/locale  file matchs the changes. Check Lollypop runs without issues.

***Also:***

You can manually update your locales specs:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Notice your language format. It should be "en_IN.utf8" or "en_IN.UTF-8" **(*)**

Now, edit your enviroment file:

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/environment
```

Add a new line with:

```
LANG="en_IN.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_IN"
```

Replaced "en_IN.UTF-8" by "en_IN.utf8" according **(*)**.

Save and close the file. Now edit your locale file:

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/default/locale
```

Delete all the content and type:

```
LANG="en_IN.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_IN.UTF-8"
```

Replaced "en_IN.UTF-8" by "en_IN.utf8" according **(*)**. Save and close file.

At last, in terminal:

```
sudo update-locale
```

To check that all is well, type in terminal

```
locale
```

This command should throw you the same content as we stuck in the last step. If so, reboot and try again with Lollypop.

Comment: No, its not working. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Ajith, I edited the answer with some clarifications. I hope it help you.