# After update all settings in system settings -> languages and regions are empty

Tags: settings, keyboard, language, keyboard-layout

Now i have installed OS the third time...

Everytime after the installation i can set the language/the systemlanguage to GERMAN.
When i make the update my keyboard layout is us and the settings are empty.
Then i set the settings to german, but when i close the systemsettings and reopen them - there are no languages set, and there are no languages available on the left side.

i have google the problem and make everyone of the tipps - but nothing works...

please help me!

Comment: Perhaps the writing-rights of a special folder or document are not right?

Comment: You can try to update your "locale" variables. Try with this Q&A:

http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/unicode-locale-error-while-running-lollypop-music-player/1343#1343